# how to printf pre-defined cflags

Tags: c++, printf, cflags

I have a simple cpp file as following on Unix environment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef HELLO
    #define HELLO    "hello"
#endif

int main()
{
    printf("HELLO = %s \n", HELLO);
    return 0;
}
```

If this was compiled and ran, it prints out `HELLO = HELLO`.

However, when I do export `HELLO="HELLO"`, then compile the program using `g++ -Wall -g -DHELLO`, I get a warning saying:

```
    warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 2 has type     ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("HELLO = %s \n", HELLO);
```

When I run the program, I get a segmentation fault.

How would I print `-DHELLO` in the code?

Comment: `-DHELLO` is equivalent to `#define HELLO 1`, hence you get incorrect code. You need to do `'-DHELLO="hello"'` (you can check this by directly invoking preprocessor `cpp`: `echo 'HELLO' | cpp -DHELLO`)

Answer (score 1):

`-DHELLO` is equivalent to `#define HELLO 1`, which explains the compilation error, which complaints about an `int`, rather than a `char*`.

Try compiling like this:

```
g++ -Wall -g -DHELLO="hello"
```